# When is MPI_Wait necessary for non-blocking calls?

Tags: parallel-computing, mpi, c

I hope this is not too off-topic here -- I've asked it on SO but I'm hoping I'll get better answers here!

---

I'm a little bit confused about when I should call MPI_Wait (or other variants such as: MPI_Waitall, MPII_Waitsome, etc). Consider the following situations: (Note: pseudo code)

Case (1)

```
MPI_Isend (send_buffer, send_req);    
// Do local work
MPI_Probe (recv_msg);
MPI_Irecv (recv_buffer, recv_req);
// wait for msgs to finish
MPI_Wait (recv_req);   // <--- Is this needed?
MPI_Wait (send_req);   // <--- How about this?
```

So my confusion stems from `MPI_Probe` in this case. Since this is a blocking call, wouldn't that essentially mean it blocks the caller until message is received? If this is the case, then I think MPI_Waits are unnecessary here.

How about the following case?

Case (2)

```
MPI_Isend (send_buffer, send_req);    
// Do local work
MPI_Probe (recv_msg);
MPI_Recv (recv_buffer);
// wait for msgs to finish
MPI_Wait (send_req);   // <--- Is this necessary?
```

Similar to the first case but `MPI_Irecv` is replaced with its blocking version. In this case, the message is definitely received by the time `MPI_Wait` is called which means `MPI_Isend` must have been finished ...

Also as a separate question, what do we mean when we say `MPI_Probe` is blocking? Does it block until all of the message is received by the process or does it only block until "meta-data" (such as msg size, sender rank, etc) is received? In other words is `MPI_Probe` + `MPI_Irecv` any better than `MPI_Probe` + `MPI_Recv` ?

Comment: You must always wait on or test nonblocking operations if you'd like your programs to be standard compliant and hence portable. The standard allows the implementation to postpone the actual data transmission until the wait/test call. Some MPI operations (other than wait/test) progress non-blocking operations but one should not rely on this behaviour.

Comment: @HristoIliev Can you elaborate on what you mean by "The standard allows the implementation to postpone the actual data transmission until the wait/test call."? Is this always the case? If not, what conditions does the postponement of data transmission depend on?

Comment: @niran90 It means that an operation initiated by `MPI_Isend` does not necessarily progress in the background but only when the MPI implementation is given the chance to progress it. `MPI_Wait` progresses the operation and guarantees its completion. Some MPI implementations can progress operations in the background using progression threads. Some cannot. It is implementation-dependent and one should never rely on one or another specific behaviour.

Comment: @HristoIliev I see. In the case of `MPI_Test`, does the progression of `MPI_Isend` depend on the number of times `MPI_Test` is called? Or is one call sufficient to provoke `MPI_Isend` to commence progression?

Comment: @niran90 That's depends on the implementation. `MPI_Test` is meant to be called in a loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bill answered the first part, so I'll only answer the second question.  An MPI send is blocking if it does not return until it is safe to modify the send buffer and a receive is blocking if it does not return until the receive buffer contains the newly-received message.  In practice, outside of buffered sends (thanks, Hristo Iliev), this implies that communication may be required before returning.  For example, `MPI_Send` is blocking because it cannot complete before the message has been buffered or sent.  Implementations will usually "eagerly" buffer short messages, in which case `MPI_Send` appears to return immediately.  This means that code looks like:

```
MPI_Send(&x,count,MPI_INT,(rank+1)%size,1,comm);
MPI_Recv(&y,count,MPI_INT,(size+rank-1)%size,1,comm,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

is expected to deadlock for large messages, although it will likely succeed for small enough messages.  Nonblocking sends and receives return `MPI_Request`s that must be completed before buffers are accessed/modified.

Some operations are a bit different from sends and receives. `MPI_Probe` is blocking because it does not return until a message has been found, although the message need not have been received yet.  `MPI_Iprobe` is non-blocking in that it always returns even if there is no message.

Comment: This is not true. Blocking means that return from the procedure indicates that the user is allowed to reuse the resources specified in the call, e.g. the data buffer (see §2.4 of the MPI standard). For example `MPI_Bsend` always buffers the message and is still a blocking call.

Comment: @HristoIliev You're completely right, I wasn't thinking about buffered-mode. I've updated and expanded the answer.

Answer (score 5):

[MPI_Probe](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node50.htm) allows you to test for a message without actually receiving it. You *must* complete all non-blocking communications with an appropriate communications completion fuction like MPI_Wait and friends, otherwise the runtime will not free up internal resources associated with the communications leading to resource leaks and other problems. For example, you may not reuse the send message buffer for anything else until the communication has been completed with an appropriate completion call.

Comment: I see. But still I have my other question. Does MPI_Probe block the process until ALL of the message is received or does it return as soon as it figures out the length of message and sending process?

Comment: @GradGuy It only needs to determine the size.  Some implementations might eagerly receive small messages, but quality implementations won't buffer large messages because that could use an excessive amount of memory.

Comment: @JedBrown That's what I was hoping for but could not find much info on the web. Thanks Jed.

Answer (score 1):

Every time that you use an `MPI_Request` in an MPI function, you either have to wait for it to finish using any of the `MPI_Wait` functions or keep on doing `MPI_Test` on it until the flag returns non-zero.

This includes all functions that start with `MPI_I` (non-blocking sends, receives and collectives) and functions that cancel a some non-blocking operation e.g.

```
int i = 0;
MPI_Request req = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;
MPI_Isend( &i, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req );
MPI_Cancel( &req );
MPI_Wait( &req, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE ); // you have to wait
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right that there are situations where you can determine by reasoning that an `Isend` or `Irecv` has been concluded, and so you don't have to do a `Wait` semantically. In that case, the only reason for doing the wait is that the "I" operation allocates an `MPI_Request` object and you need to deallocate it. So the wait prevents memory leaks. You can also use `MPI_Request_free` to deallocate the request object.